# Rollback not working on Spring Boot @Transactional method for H2 database

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, transactions, h2

Please give me tips to get my failing JUnit test to pass in my Spring Boot app.

I have a Service that needs to delete rows from tables A and B (from a H2 database) in a transactional manner such that: if A is modified and then an exception occurs before B is modified, then neither A nor B are modified. However, even after

1. Adding `@Transactional` to the PUBLIC `Service::deleteRows` method, and
2. Adding `@EnableTransactionManagement` to the `@Configuration` class that produces the `JdbcTemplate` that all repositories use, and
3. Confirming that spring-tx is on the classpath

the transaction still doesn't rollback.

Here's the failing JUnit testcase

```java
// Service.java
@Transactional
public void deleteRows() {
    aRepository.deleteRow(123);
    bRepository.deleteRow(123);
}
```

```java
// ServiceTest.java
@Test
void test() {​
    // first ensure that an exception is thrown when bRepository.deleteRow() is called
    // FYI deleteRow() calls jdbcTemplate.update()
    doThrow(RuntimeException.class)
        .when(mockJdbcTemplate)
        .update(any(), eq(123));
    BRepository mockBRepository = new BRepository(mockJdbcTemplate);
    Service service = new Service(realARepository, mockBRepository);

    assertTableHasRows(1, "TABLE_A");                          // before calling the service, TABLE_A has 1 row

    assertThrows(RuntimeException.class, service::deleteRows);    

    assertTableHasRows(1, "TABLE_A");                          // TABLE_A should still have 1 row when an exception occurs during the tx
}​
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end the problem was solved by NOT using mocking to trigger an exception. Instead, we set up the database schema so that normal operation of service::deleteRows would trigger an exception.

Answer (score 0):

Remove @Transactional and run test again.

Comment: Hi Amir Rad, thanks for the tip. The test failed even after removing @Transactional. What's your theory for why removing the annotation would work?

Comment: The transactional annotation defines the scope of a single database transaction. The database transaction happens inside the scope of a persistence context. The persistence context is in JPA the EntityManager, implemented internally using an Hibernate Session. The persistence context is just a synchronizer object that tracks the state of a limited set of Java objects and makes sure that changes on those objects are eventually persisted back into the database.

Comment: why don't you use "DeleteById" method for deleting one object? This method implemented by JpaRepository and easily can be used.